# How to preserve line breaks in a content editable div when using .text() - Jquery

Tags: jquery, newline

I have a div which is having "contenteditable=true". When i enter text in it, and press enter the cursor goes to the next line by appending `<br>` in the previous line.

While I use the submit button, I use `.text()` to get the contents of the div. This strips of any html tags in the div, thus removing all the `<br>` tags. So no line breaks.

I wanna know, how do i preserve line breaks when submitting the form. Thanks for help...

Comment: Why not use a `textarea` and `.val()`? It preserves whitespace.

Comment: I cant use textarea, due to some other feature which only works with content editable elements and not textareas. @ahren

Answer (score 12):

Don't use Jquery for this, the `.text()` function removes white space. Use plain Javascript for this:

```
$(selector)[0].innerText = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.text()` you can use `.html()`. This won't strip the tags out. Your next problem will be trying to eliminate/convert the  tags..

You can check out more about `.html()` here: http://api.jquery.com/html.

Answer (score 0):

innerText, outerText attributes doesn't work with jQuery. 
Use native JS style.

`window.document.getElementById("ced").innerText;`

Comment: innerText doesn't work directly on the result of a jQuery selector such as $(selector).innerText, you have to select an individual item from the result: $(selector)[0].innerText